# Invoke-Command with local function in ScriptBlock doesn't work when the function has no return statement

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet working with a CredSsp session by passing a locally defined function.

I have two local functions:

- `MyCopy` which just invokes Copy-Item cmdlet on passed params with additional switches
- `MyCopyReturn` which is the same as above, but in addition has `return` statement at the end

Now when I pass those functions to `Invoke-Command` without `-Session` parameter, they both succeed.
However, when specifying `-Session` for `Invoke-Command`, `MyCopy` fails with following exception (2. case):

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

Could someone please explain why result of passing `MyCopyReturn` is different from passing `MyCopy`?

```
function MyCopy ($from, $to) {
    Copy-Item $from $to -Force -Recurse -Verbose
}

function MyCopyReturn ($from, $to) {
    Copy-Item $from $to -Force -Recurse -Verbose
    return
}

$credential = Get-Credential
$computerName = 'localhost'
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $credential -Authentication Credssp
# src is a file
$src = "c:\sandbox\a\test"
# dest is a directory
$dest = "c:\sandbox\b"

# 1.
# MyCopy works fine without giving session
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ${function:MyCopy} -ArgumentList $src,$dest

# 2.
# MyCopy DOESN'T WORK when session is given
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock ${function:MyCopy} -ArgumentList $src,$dest

# 4.
# MyCopyReturn works fine without the session
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ${function:MyCopyReturn} -ArgumentList $src,$dest

# 3.
# MyCopyReturn works fine with session too
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock ${function:MyCopyReturn} -ArgumentList $src,$dest

Remove-PSSession $session
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make some digging with ILSpy and can say, that the problem in the bug in `ScriptBlock.GetPowerShell` method. It does not bind parameters properly, if them come not from `param` block:

```
function f($Arg){write "`$Arg=`"$Arg`";`$Args=`"$Args`""}
function g{param($Arg) write "`$Arg=`"$Arg`";`$Args=`"$Args`""}

$Function:f.GetPowerShell('Test1','Test2').Invoke()
# $Arg="";$Args="Test1 Test2"
$Function:g.GetPowerShell('Test1','Test2').Invoke()
# $Arg="Test1";$Args="Test2"
```

As you can see, `$Function:f.GetPowerShell('Test1','Test2')` bind both arguments to `$Args` automatic variable and nothing get bound to `$Arg`. So when you invoke this command

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock ${function:MyCopy} -ArgumentList $src,$dest
```

`$from` and `$to` does not get bound properly and cause error.

Why error does not happens when you not use `-Session` parameter?
Looks like `Invoke-Command` have to convert `ScriptBlock` to `PowerShell` to invoke command in remote session and that does not required when `ScriptBlock` invoked locally.

Why `MyCopyReturn` does not cause same error?
Not all `ScripBlock`s can be converted to PowerShell by `GetPowerShell` method (in particular, it is required that `ScriptBlock` must have a single statement, having another statement `return` violate this). If that is the case (`GetPowerShell` throws `ScriptBlockToPowerShellNotSupportedException`), than `Invoke-Command` use some backup scenario to convert `ScriptBlock` to `PowerShell` and that scenario does not suffer from bug of `GetPowerShell` method.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that if I have a non-single statement function and specify arguments outside the function body (not in `param` block), then `Invoke-Command` with session works properly by using some fallback solution?

Comment: that's a really strange behavior from POV of `Invoke-Command`. Anyway thanks for the answer!